# Create a small web installer using Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, advanced-installer

I have created a software suite installer using Inno Setup.

What I would like to do is to create a small installer and when executed, will download and execute that software suite installer.

I know Advanced Installer has that package type:

**Web Installer (downloadable small EXE)**

**Creates a single EXE file that will download MSI and install MSI from an URL.**

How does Inno Setup create that?

thanks

Comment: I'm using GetWebInstaller. It supports downloading exe from web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inno Setup does not have this as a "feature", that is not how it works.

You can achieve required behavior in Inno by creating simple installer and modifying the [Code] section.

Use **ITD Download plug-in** to download required files (you need to save appropriate URLs in script) and execute them (with parameters) in script.

It is more work as you need to handle everything in script but you can achieve better results as you have full control of everything.